# Use Razorpay Nodejs SDK in Nest JS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, razorpay

I am trying to use  [Razorpay Nodejs SDK](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-node) in Nest JS application

Here are 2 ways that I tried to use the razorpay instance

Method 1

```
@Injectable()
export class OrdersService {
  private razorpay: Razorpay;
  constructor(
    private readonly logger: Logger,
    @InjectRepository(BreOrders)
    private readonly orderRepository: Repository<BreOrders>,
  ) {
    this.razorpay = new Razorpay({
      key_id: "YOUR_KEY_ID",
      key_secret: "YOUR_KEY_SECRET",
    });
  }
 }
```

which gives error `TypeError: razorpay_1.default is not a constructor`

Method 2

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([BreOrders]), EmailModule],
  controllers: [OrdersController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Razorpay,
      useFactory: () =>
        new Razorpay({
          key_id: process.env.RAZORPAY_KEY,
          key_secret: process.env.RAZORPAY_SECRET,
        }),
    },
    OrdersService,
    Logger,
  ],
  exports: [OrdersService],
})
export class OrdersModule {}
```

```
export class OrdersService {
  constructor(
    private readonly logger: Logger,
    @InjectRepository(BreOrders)
    private readonly orderRepository: Repository<BreOrders>,
    private readonly razorpay: Razorpay,
  ) {}
```

which gives error  `ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the OrdersService (Logger, BreOrdersRepository, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [2] is available in the OrdersModule context.`

Comment: This is most likely an issue with how you are importing the constructor from the package.

Comment: Fixed by adding `"esModuleInterop": true, into tsconfig.json.`